# np.vectorize() on np.array versus np.ndarray (what's the difference?)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, vectorization

I have a function that takes in a list (or equivalent) and performs some computation on it, before spitting out an output.
My goal is to apply this function over a very long list of lists, and in my pursuit, I found that what I'm attempting works when I use np.ndarray but not np.array, and I'm unable to figure out why.

Here is a simpler version of what I'm doing to compare:

```
def f(some_input):
    return sum(some_input)
f_vec = np.vectorize(f)

""" #1: ndarray """
array1 = np.ndarray((2,), dtype=object)
array1[0] = [1.0, 1.5, 3.5]
array1[1] = [9.1, 2.8, 0.1]

""" #2: array """
array2 = np.array([[1.0, 1.5, 3.5],
                   [9.1, 2.8, 0.1]], dtype=object)
```

When I run f_vec() on array1, I get the intended output:

```
In [1]: f_vec(array1)
array([ 6., 12.])
```

But I get a TypeError when I run f_vec() on array2 (TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable).

I've read the documentations and I think I have a rough sense of the differences of an array and a ndarray (the former is a function that returns the latter object) but I still don't know why I can't run np.vectorize() on my np.array. I played around with np.array but still struggling, so would appreciate some help.

Thank you.

Comment: I'll assume "sum" isn't the actual operation you wish to perform (otherwise, just use np.sum). Vectorize applies this to each element of the array. In the first case, it's it's a 1D array of list, the second, it's a 2D array of floats. You could have a 1D array of 1D arrays of floats if you wanted. Or just loop/np.apply_along_axis. I don't think vectorize allows you to specify dimensions (nor does it improve performance anyway)

Comment: thank you @MikaelÖhman and yes, "sum" was just an easy operation I chose for the demonstration. Understood, so its in the difference in dimensionality. Thanks again

Comment: If you care about performance, note that `object` will prevent a true vectorization to be applied by Numpy. Numpy will just use an inefficient loop internally. In fact, `np.vectorize` also do that even on natively-typed arrays. `object`-typed array should really be avoided using Numpy. It is just provided for convenience, not performance. Using list should actually be faster (at least with an optimized implementation).

Answer (score 1):

When playing with `np.vectorize`, pay close attention to what arguments it is passing to your function.  Don't just assume - test. Also pay attention to the `otypes` and performance notes in the documentation.

First lets be clear about the two arrays.  Both are `ndarray`.  You just used the low level `ndarray` function to create a 1d `object` dtype array containing lists.

```
In [296]: array1
Out[296]: array([list([1.0, 1.5, 3.5]), list([9.1, 2.8, 0.1])], dtype=object)

In [297]: array2
Out[297]: 
array([[1.0, 1.5, 3.5],
       [9.1, 2.8, 0.1]], dtype=object)

In [298]: type(array1)
Out[298]: numpy.ndarray

In [299]: type(array2)
Out[299]: numpy.ndarray
```

`array2` is object dtype as well, but it is 2d, with float elements.

I would have initialized `array1` with `array1 = np.empty((2,), dtype=object)`.  The result is the same `array([None, None], dtype=object)`.

From the `ndarray` docs:

```
Arrays should be constructed using `array`, `zeros` or `empty` (refer
to the See Also section below).  The parameters given here refer to
a low-level method (`ndarray(...)`) for instantiating an array.
```

---

The python `sum` function expects an iterable - a list, or array, not a single number:

```
In [292]: f([1,2,3])
Out[292]: 6

In [293]: f(1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [293], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 f(1)

Input In [291], in f(some_input)
      1 def f(some_input):
----> 2     return sum(some_input)

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Let's modify `f` to show the input as well:

```
def f(some_input):
    print(some_input)
    return sum(some_input)
```

Now run the `vectorized` version:

```
In [300]: f_vec(array1)
[1.0, 1.5, 3.5]
[1.0, 1.5, 3.5]
[9.1, 2.8, 0.1]
Out[300]: array([ 6., 12.])
```

See, it's passing each of the 3 lists that are in the 1d `array1`.  Sum of a list is fine.  By the way, that first call is a "test" that determines the return dtype.

But with `array2`, which is 2d float dtype, it passes **scalar** values, not rows:

```
In [301]: f_vec(array2)
1.0
...
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

We can just iterate on the rows/elements of the arrays with:

```
In [302]: [f(x) for x in array2]
[1.0 1.5 3.5]
[9.1 2.8 0.1]
Out[302]: [6.0, 11.999999999999998]

In [303]: [f(x) for x in array1]
[1.0, 1.5, 3.5]
[9.1, 2.8, 0.1]
Out[303]: [6.0, 11.999999999999998]
```

`np.vectorize` has a performance disclaimer.  I have found that with large problems it does have something of a speed advantage of the equivalent list comprehension, but it is not "true vectorization".  It does not compile your function.

I don't know if I should mention this, but we can use `signature` to get a version that does work with the 2d array:

```
In [312]: f_vec = np.vectorize(f, otypes=[float], signature='(n)->()')
In [313]: f_vec(array2)
[1.0 1.5 3.5]
[9.1 2.8 0.1]
Out[313]: array([ 6., 12.])
```

It is slower than the default version; and doesn't work with your `array1`.

The "true vectorized" calculation would be:

```
In [319]: np.sum(array2, axis=1)
Out[319]: array([6.0, 11.999999999999998], dtype=object)
```

or better with float dtype:

```
In [320]: np.sum(array2.astype(float), axis=1)
Out[320]: array([ 6., 12.])
```

If we replace the python `sum` with `np.sum` which doesn't have problems with scalars:

```
In [321]: def f(some_input):
     ...:     print(some_input)
     ...:     return np.sum(some_input)
     ...: f_vec = np.vectorize(f)

In [322]: f_vec(array1)
[1.0, 1.5, 3.5]
[1.0, 1.5, 3.5]
[9.1, 2.8, 0.1]
Out[322]: array([ 6., 12.])
```

`array2` does run - but again, it's getting the individual elements, not the rows:

```
In [323]: f_vec(array2)
1.0
1.0
1.5
3.5
9.1
2.8
0.1
Out[323]: 
array([[1. , 1.5, 3.5],
       [9.1, 2.8, 0.1]])
```